# Return global object using this keyword from function

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, this

It is not related to **Javascript** purely. I am using **NodeJS**.

```
var common_admin_users_param = {
    Limit:      60,
    GroupName: "admin",
    NextToken:  undefined
};

function getAdminUserParams() { 
    alert(this.common_admin_users_param); // undefined
}

getAdminUserParams();
```

I am wondering why it is giving me undefined.

My requirement is that my **common_admin_users_param** is global variable having some default values.

But i want the unique copy of this global variable for each session. So, I made **function** which will return current instance of this global variable.

Any help?

Code snippet: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mz593cy7/12/)

> (It is now working :))

Comment: Did you try `window.common_admin_users_param`? If that method is not inside a class, you cannot use `this`...

Comment: Ah, the infamous `this` scope issue. Yet again. Google for articles explaining how `this` works.

Comment: I am using node js. So window will not work for me :)

Comment: use global.yourobject = {} ; alert(global.yourobject) in node environment instead of window to make them available globally through global